# how to display civi's navigation menu on custom page (eg Drupal view path)

Tags: drupal

If I create a page (like a view in Drupal) I can add a link to it in Civi's Navigation Menu.  But then you go to that page and the Navigation Menu disappears.  The path for that page is `/civicrm/something-custom` but apparently starting with `civicrm/*` doesn't automagically display the menu.  **How can I make the menu appear on custom pages?**

A method via code (hook_something would be better than hack_something) would be sufficient, as I don't see any options in the UI at `civicrm/admin/menu`.

[The docs](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_navigationMenu/) list a `hook_civicrm_navigationMenu` but it sounds like it only alters the menu itself, as opposed to allowing me to display it when it's not otherwise displayed.

I did a `grep` through the codebase for `civicrm-menu` and `sites/all/modules/civicrm/templates/CRM/common/navigation.js.tpl` looked the most promosing but wasn't enlightening itself, then I saw that `sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Admin/Page/AJAX.php` prints that file inside of a `public static function getNavigationMenu()` and there's a comment for that function `@see smarty_function_crmNavigationMenu`.  But searching the web doesn't yield any results on invoking these functions in custom code.

Surely this has been done before... right?  Is there a proper method for doing so?